# What kind of type of values in JavaScript corresponds to Java`List<>`?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I use a node.js package for "Bridge API to connect with existing Java APIs": `node-java`.

https://github.com/joeferner/node-java

One Java API function that I need to connect is

```
  public void reqMktData(int tickerId, Contract contract, 
       String genericTicklist, boolean snapshot, List<TagValue> mktDataOptions)
  {
    m_s.reqMktData(tickerId, contract, genericTicklist, snapshot, mktDataOptions);
  }
```

The problem is I don't know how to pass Java type `List<>` from node JavaScript. `Int` or  `boolean` or others work fine.

So, here's my question.

What kind of type of values in JavaScript corresponds to Java`List<>`?

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably an array.

Comment: I haven't used `node-java` but my assumption would be, that you can create a new class (`TagValueList`) that extends `List<TagValue>`, then in JS create an instance of it, to be populated, using `java.newInstanceSync('..TagValueList')`.  Otherwise you may need to use `TagValue[]`?

Comment: Thanks mstthealias. I missed the doc you pointed out. works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line with what [@mstrthealias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1345237/mstrthealias) said, the example on the project's GitHub page says,

```
var list = java.newInstanceSync("java.util.ArrayList");

java.newInstance("java.util.ArrayList", function(err, list) {
  if(err) { console.error(err); return; }
  // new list
});
```

Comment: Thanks GreyBeardedGeek. I missed the project doc you have pointed out. In fact, ``` var ArrayList = java.import('java.util.ArrayList');
  var list = new ArrayList(); ``` worked.